# Syntactic tree of a simple instruction : A = 2+3 

Tags: erlang

i was wondering if anyone could help me drawing the syntactic tree of a very very simple instruction in erlang :  a simple assignment like        A =  2  +  3.          using , of course the erlang official grammar available at http://svn.ulf.wiger.net/indent/trunk/erl_parse.yrl

Thanks for everything

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use Erlang own tools:

```
1> {ok, Toks, _} = erl_scan:string("A=2+3.").
{ok,[{var,1,'A'},
     {'=',1},
     {integer,1,2},
     {'+',1},
     {integer,1,3},
     {dot,1}],
    1}
2> {ok, [AST]} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Toks).
{ok,[{match,1,
            {var,1,'A'},
            {op,1,'+',{integer,1,2},{integer,1,3}}}]}
3> AST.
{match,1,{var,1,'A'},{op,1,'+',{integer,1,2},{integer,1,3}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , sir. I would like you to help me if possible to parse an expression like "A=2.   B=4." which i had quite a lot of trouble with .

Comment: @homebrew: Try "A=2, B=4." instead.